# Facebook image upload from local storage

Tags: angular, facebook-graph-api, image-uploading

I'm using Facebook graph API to post an Image to a page.

```
 UploadImage() {

let params = {
  url: "https://www.facebook.com/images/fb_icon_325x325.png",
  published: true,
  access_token: this.accessToken
};

this.fb.api('/543337362691456/photos', 'post', params).then().catch(this.handleError); }
```

This code works perfectly. But I want to select a file from computer and upload that image to facebook. In order to do that, How I'm suppose to set the url of a local file to

```
url:" "
```

if I just select the path of a file it gives an error

[Error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DyS94.png)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `url` parameter is for online/public photos only, the picture needs to be on a server already. Take a look at the API reference, you can also upload them as `multipart/form-data`: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/reference/page/photos/#Creating

Example: http://www.devils-heaven.com/facebook-javascript-sdk-photo-upload-with-formdata/

Comment: Can you please elaborate more on how to use `multipart/form-data` .

Comment: maybe if you have a sample project or a tutorial that I can follow. I have no Idea how to send form data to facebook graph API.

Comment: there you go: http://www.devils-heaven.com/facebook-javascript-sdk-photo-upload-with-formdata/

Comment: How is uploading a picture done nowadays, since this API call was removed by Facebook?

Answer (score 0):

To Upload image using form-data see the image below
[image]

Answer (score 0):

```
def post_image():
    msg = 'Purple Ombre Bob Lace Wig Natural Human Hair now available on https://lace-wigs.co.za/'
    image_path = '/path/to/local/image.jpg'
    files = {'photo': open(image_path, 'rb')}
    post_url = 'https://graph.facebook.com/{}/photos?access_token={}'.format(page_id, facebook_access_token)
    payload = {
        'message': msg
    }
    r = requests.post(post_url, data=payload, files=files)
    print(r.text)
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).