# Node.js - Send file to Facebook Graph Api

Tags: node.js, facebook-graph-api, multer

I need to upload images and other content to Facebook from a Node.js backend. My API only make requests using the Graph API endpoints, and I don't want to use unofficial Node.js SDKs.

I can send files from my front end and retrieve them using multer. However I don't want to save them to a directory, but send them directly to a Graph API endpoint like `https://graph.facebook.com/<page-id>/photos?access_token=<token-id>`

What should I do to achieve that?

Edit:

Here's what I have for the moment. Multer save the file as binary data in an `uploads` directory

```
router.post('/profile/:idProfile/post', upload.any(), (req, res) => {
  const path = req.params.idProfile + '/photos';

  console.log(req.files[0]);

  // A facebook superset module created for my app
  facebook.post(path, req.files[0])
    .then((res2) => {
      if (res2.error) {
        res.send(res2)
      } else {
        res.send({
          code: 200,
          data: req.files[0]
        });
      }
    });
});
```

I have the following errors:

```
{
  "code": 400,
  "error": {
    "message": "(#324) Requires upload file",
    "type": "OAuthException",
    "code": 324,
    "fbtrace_id": "E5FGvbwN2Gs"
  }
}
```

Comment: so did you check out the graph api docs and do some testing? please add your code. i know for a fact that there is a part in the /me/photos api reference telling you about uploading photos without an URL.

Comment: btw, i believe posting to a user profile´with the api is not possible anymore. you should check out the breaking changes in the changelog.

Comment: @luschn Edited. This is possible, I've done it by putting the Graph API endpoint in my form action attribute

Comment: "The publish_actions permission has been removed. Apps that have already been approved for publish_actions can continue using the permission until August 1st, 2018" - are you actually talking about a USER profile (since you mentioned /me instead of a page id) or a PAGE?

Comment: `/me` was for the example, in fact I'm publishing to pages and groups. I'm going to edit this

Comment: maybe this helps: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48710323/facebook-image-upload-from-local-storage