# Node.js - Axios - Upload file to another server

Tags: node.js, facebook-graph-api, file-upload, axios, multer

I need to upload a file from a Node.js server to another server using axios. I'm using multer to handle the data received from the client. Here's my code:

```
const multer = require('multer');
const router = require('express').Router();
const FormData = require('form-data');
const fs = require('fs');

router.post('/profile/:idProfile/post', upload.any(), (req, res) => {
  const file = req.files[0];
  const url = 'https://graph.facebook.com/' + req.params.idProfile + '/photos?access_token=<my-access-token>';
  const fd = new FormData();
  const config = {
    headers: { 'Content-Type': 'multipart/form-data' }
  };

  fd.append('file', fs.createReadStream(file.path), file.path);

  axios.post(url, fd, config)
    .then((res2) => {
      res.send(res2);
    })
    .catch((err) => {
      res.send({
        code: err.response.status,
        error: err.response.data.error
      });
    });
});
```

I don't see any problems, but I'm still getting the following error from Facebook's Graph API:

```
{
  "code": 400,
  "error": {
    "message": "(#324) Requires upload file",
    "type": "OAuthException",
    "code": 324,
    "fbtrace_id": "HeA2joMhLQ7"
  }
}
```

I already tried to upload files directly to the Facebook Graph Api url from a simple html page with success. But I'm not able to understand what's missing here

Comment: the question is a bit misleading...you actually just want to upload a photo to facebook, and it does not exist on a webserver but comes with a form input. this could help you: https://www.devils-heaven.com/facebook-javascript-sdk-photo-upload-with-formdata/

Comment: btw, is this for user profiles or pages on facebook?

Comment: @luschn pages. This is related to my previous question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51466732/node-js-send-file-to-facebook-graph-api?noredirect=1#comment89913797_51466732

Comment: so what is the difference to the other question then? you are just using axios instead of some other sdk, but it is the exact same thing with the exact same error. did you try the code in my article? i did post it in the other thread too.

Comment: @luschn Yes I tried the code. But, I finally found the solution here https://github.com/axios/axios/issues/318

Answer (score 1):

I found the solution to my problem. I needed to use fd.pipe() and concat to send the image with axios because it's in a binary format:

```
fd.pipe(concat({ encoding: 'buffer' }, (data) => {
  axios.post(url, data, { headers: fd.getHeaders() });
}));
```

[There's more details on this issue here](https://github.com/axios/axios/issues/318)

Comment: You are such a life-savior. I spent an whole day figuring out this matter.

Answer (score 0):

```
//Concat the formData.
const concatenated = await new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    formData.pipe(concat({ encoding: 'buffer' }, async (data) => {
        resolve(data);
    }))
})

//Now you can use it.
const resp = await axios.post(
    `${URL_BASE}/upload_file`,
    concatenated,
    {
        headers: {...formData.getHeaders()}
    }
);
```